# Android mediaplayer does not stop on checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, media-player, media

I built a small app which basically vibrates and plays an mp3 file on checking a checkbox, but somehow the music won't stop after unchecking the checkbox:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        final CheckBox vibrateBoxStrong = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkPowerStrong);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        vibrateBoxStrong.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fansound1);
                    if(vibrateBoxStrong.isChecked()) {
                        handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
                        vibrator.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time the `CheckBox` changes its checked state, you create a new `MediaPlayer` instance, so you're calling `stop()` on the wrong instance.

Comment: hmm ok, how should I change it to call the correct object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Playing mp3

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.aaanicholas);
```

to start

```
mPlayer.start();
```

to stop

```
mPlayer.stop();
```

In your case use

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.aaanicholas);
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        final CheckBox vibrateBoxStrong = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkPowerStrong);


        vibrateBoxStrong.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fansound1);
                    if(vibrateBoxStrong.isChecked()) {
                        v.vibrate(1000);            // it will vibrate for 1000 milliseconds
                        mPlayer.start();         
                    } else {
                        mPlayer.stop();

                        vibrator.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: so I do not need this object `mediaPlayer `?

Comment: I can't get you "restarting of check"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112073/discussion-between-vishwesh-jainkuniya-and-alex-oxilg).